# how to make navigation Bar move above its position smoothly,

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I used UIScrolView to show the Contents(Images). I didn't use any third party code. My Scroller and zooming are working perfectly(which were not working before). Now I want to add a functionality, where after just touching the screen(i.e tapping once) the Navigation Bar goes up as shown in Picture2. I want to increase the size of the UIscrollview at the same time, as shown in Image 2. And If the user Tap Once again the Navigation Bar , come back to its original position and the scrollView gets back to its original size and shape. My scrollView is containing Images, that scrolls Horizontally.

[image: Image1 before tapping]

[image: Image2 after tapping]

One way to show animation for Navigation Bar, is that I make a custom View and add it on the place of Navigation Bar and Use following code for animation
For Moving Upward

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    customNavigationbar_view.frame=CGRectMake(0, -66, 320, 65);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Which will become too clumsy. Am even ready to do that. But how To increase my scrollview size with animation, so that It doesnt appear that Scrollview size increase immmidately my clicking something. If there's a third party that provide all the things I want like this, please let me know. Most of Third Party code is either to hard to get or they dont provide all the things I require in my project. And am sorry for the way I added Images.

Comment: Have you tried the `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` method of UINavigationController?

Comment: @titaniumdecoy Thanks a ton. It solved 50% of my current problem. How Can I show transition for the MY SCROLLVIEW, I have to show transition with its increase size. am sorry If am not able to illustarte properly

Comment: Did you set UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight on the UIScrollView?

Comment: @titaniumdecoy no idea about that, just looked on google, stackoverflow, and Found this
[scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
 it also didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate the change in the scrollview frame:
Something like:

```
- (void) tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated: YES];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height; // or whatever you need to keep it from moving up
        self.scrollView.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated: YES];
```

See [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden%3aanimated%3a)

To make your `scrollView` move with the navbar, you'll need to set your autoLayout to pin the top of the `scrollView` to the top of the `viewContoller`'s view.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It solved 50% of my current problem. How Can I show transition for the MY SCROLLVIEW, I have to show transition with its increase size. as I showed in the above added Images. am sorry If am not able to illustarte properly

Comment: am sorry, am not much experineced. Is there any sample code example doing that?